# conflict between \include and the \hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, incompatibility, include

In the MWE below, an error is thrown by the command sequence `pdflatex mwe ; pdflatex mwe` when mwe.tex is

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\includeonly{}
\begin{document}
\include{refFile}
Blah blah
\ref{eq:label}
\end{document}
```

The `refFile.aux` file was generated by the file `refFile.tex` below:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:label}
x=y
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The source of the problem is the `\include` command.   If one comments that out the code compiles, but of course the `\ref{eq:label}` command doesn't work.

Could anybody please advise what's going on, and how to work around this?

Thanks very much, Leo

Comment: Why are you creating an .aux file manually? This is likely to cause trouble. If it's just for demonstration purpose, please add your real `refFile.tex` instead

Comment: Your \newlabel command is wrong with hyperref, it is missing arguments. Use a normal \label command and then check what is written to the aux-file to see the differences.

Comment: I've added the `refFile.tex` file to the question, as requested by @siracusa . It generates the `\newlabel` as listed in my original question, @Ulrike_Fischer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your are compiling `mwe.tex` and `refFile.tex` as two separate documents. This is not how `\include` is supposed to be used. All included documents should only contain actual document contents, but no `\documentclass`, `\usepackage`, `\begin{document}` etc. When I try to compile both files as separate documents, the following error pops up:

```
Runaway argument?
{\@firstoffive }\fi  \end {document}
! File ended while scanning use of \Hy@setref@link.
```

So you should rewrite your files such that `mwe.tex` is the main document with the full document structure:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\includeonly{}

\begin{document}
\include{refFile}
Blah blah
\ref{eq:label}
\end{document}
```

The included sub-file `refFile.tex` then looks like this:

```
\begin{align}
\label{eq:label}
x=y
\end{align}
```

Note that `\includeonly{}` won't include any sub-files and thus leave you with undefined references. If you remove that line, the resulting document correctly references your equation.

If you really want to include full documents, have a look at the [sub-documents packages at CTAN](https://ctan.org/topic/subdocs).